# how to create Array of my NSObject class

Tags: iphone

I have created a new `NSObject` class as below:

```
@interface LoginObject : NSObject {

NSString *fName;
NSString *lName;
NSString *sessionId;
NSString *result;
NSString *response;
}
```

Now I can create an object of this type as:

```
LoginObject *login;
```

What do i need to do in order to create an `NSMutableArray` of my own `NSObject` class.

can any body guide?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at the `NSMutableArray` documentation here - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Use one of the init or array methods.
`arrayWithObjects` is the one I use most often.

Comment: Can u elaborate this a little. Please

Comment: can you elaborate a little please.

Comment: I would assume it'd be something along the lines of `NSMutableArray* myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[[NSLoginObject alloc] init], [[NSLoginObject alloc] init], nil];`

Answer (score 0):

In Which class you want to have this array, you can create-

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *loginObjectArray;
```

in implementation file-

```
LoginObject *myLoginObject = [[LoginObject alloc] init];
myLoginObject.fName = ---
......
[loginObjectArray addObject:myLoginObject];
....
```

Don't forget to initialize loginObjectArray.

Answer (score 0):

First create objects of your class,an array as -

```
    LoginObject *obj1 = [[LoginObject alloc]init];
    obj1.fName = @"xxxx";
    -----------

    LoginObject *obj1 = [[LoginObject alloc]init];
    obj1.fName = @"xxxx";
    -----------

    // create a array with above objects 
    // nil indicate end of array 

    NSMutableArray *users = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:obj1,obj2,...,nil];

   //if you want you can add other objects too -
   [users addObject:obj10];
```